# Is a point inside a graphics group composed of multiple Polygons and FilledCurves, not all overlapping?

Tags: graphics, geographics

I have many thousands of points, and I want to check if they are inside a GraphicsGroup that is composed of many Polygons and FilledCurves, similar to GeoWithin but without having to make tedious cloud inquiries.

I get RegionMember Errors and besides I suspect RegionMember is too smart to do a simple 2D numerical True/False test efficiently.

I've done this once many years ago by counting if a line from the point to infinity crossed all of the polygon segments an even or odd number of times, but would expect Mathematica to have an function already.

Thanks to Ben Izd, I detail my problem below.
I define curve, a FilledCurve:

```
curve = FilledCurve[{Line[{{0, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5}}],
    Line[{ {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1} }] }];
Graphics[{
  Black, curve,
  Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[{0.6, 0.6}], Point[{0.7, 0.7}]
  } , Axes -> True]
```

Producing this FilledCurve and two test points shown in red.
[image: FilledCurve with two test points, one inside and one outside.]

I execute this code to determine if the point is outside the FilledCurve (False should be returned). But the code to check if the points are inside or outside gives this error message:

```
RegionMember[curve, Point[{0.6, 0.6}] ]
```

But the code to check if the points are inside or outside gives this error message:
[image]

Using GeoWithin I get this result but it takes much longer as it uses cloud resources.

```
GeoWithinQ[ curve, {GeoPosition[{0.6, 0.6}],GeoPosition[{0.76, 0.76}]}]
```

Properly returning: {False,True}

Notably, I was dealing with simple geometries above, not Geographic shapes, but GeoWithinQ requires GeoPositions for the points.

With large curves the GeoWithinQ call times out. :-(

In truth, I am looking to place tens of thousands of geographic points on the earth to count how many are in the Maritime Economic Zones as a function of latitude, and the source data has both Polygons and FilledCurves in the shape file. An alternative might be to convert the shape file to Polygons or similar approach.
(Source data available at https://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php) The file is

> World_EEZ _v11 _ 20191118/eez_v11.shp

Your help is appreciated.
Steve

Comment: I don't think `RegionMember` recognizes `FilledCurves` as a region. It would be better to show a minimal code, so we understand your problem better.

Comment: Thank you, Ben Izd.

Comment: Use `Region[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[curve]]` to convert the `Curve` to a `Region` so it can be used inside `RegionMember`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben Izd. Your approach has been very helpful, and reasonably fast, certainly much faster than GeoWithinQ can be.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben Izd. Your approach has been very helpful, and reasonably fast, certainly much faster than GeoWithinQ can be.  Sadly, out of 281 FilledCurves or Polygons, 31 could not be converted to Regions without hanging or crashing Mathematica.  I'm manually combing through the data but haven't yet noticed anything other than complexity to explain this problem.